# How to run a thread after every 25min in jmeter

Tags: testing, timer, jmeter, jsr223

I am hitting a rest API using HTTP GET request that contains authentication token in header. So in a thread group i am hitting authentication server to get authentication token. In the subsequent thread groups i am going for HTTP GET request

```js
TEST plan (property auth)
  ThreadGroup(authentication)
    http GET to get authentication token
    extracting response and putting in auth
  
  Thread group(GET)
    http GET
    
  Thread group(GET)
    http GET
    
  and soo on
```

Here the authentication token will expire for every 25 min so i need a mechanism to generate authentication token for every 25 min with out interrupting the work of on going HTTP GET calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through the below screenshots for more details. Let me know in case you still need more help on this.

Use Beanshell Assertion to store variable into Property variable

[image: Use Beanshell Assertion to store variable into Property variable]

Use the property variable in this way to fetch the value

[image: Use the property variable in this way to fetch the value]

[image: Use the below method to set the delay for Auth Token creation]

Answer (score 1):

Just add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler (since [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) the element is known as Flow Action Control) after your `http GET to get authentication token` request and configure it to **Pause** for `1500000` milliseconds (25 minutes * 60 seconds in minute * 1000 milliseconds in second)

[image]

Comment: how to use the token created in extracting response in second and third thread groups

Comment: Convert it into a JMeter property using [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function in 1st thread group and read it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in 2nd/3rd thread groups. Check out [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it in the below manner.

```
ThreadGroup(authentication)
    http GET to get authentication token
       Extract the authentication token and save in a jmeter property variable
```

The benefit of saving token in a property variable is that you can access property variable in other thread groups as well. Once configured in the above manner, you can execute the ThreadGroup(authentication) after every 23 minutes so that it can update the Jmeter property variable (authentication token) before expiring.

To set a property variable: `${__setProperty(variable, ${variable})}`

To access a property variable: `${__property(variable)}`

You can try this at your end and let me know how it goes.

Comment: can you explain in detail or provide screen shots for the solution

Comment: i am unable to pass values from a variable in setProperty, which means when i use ${__property(variable)} it gives ${variable} as output

Comment: I have attached screenshots for your reference, and hope this would be helpful for you.